# How to delete tree in parent_id=>id structure

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, tree

I have a database table (directories) that maps a tree out using a `parent_id=>id` structure.

I have another table (files) that maps files to items in the first table `directory_id => directories.id`

What I want to be able to do is, given an id from the first table, delete all rows in the second table that are anywhere equal or upwards of the selected id in the same tree.

Then delete all rows in the first table that are equal or upwards in the same tree.

The best way to explain it is a filesystem, delete a directory, it deletes everything below it.

The only way I can think of to do this is (half pseudo code!):

```
$id = :id
$files = array();
$directories = array($id);
delete_tree($query:results, $files, $directories);

function delete_tree($id, &$files, &$directories){
    $query = SELECT `id` FROM `directories` WHERE `parent_id` = $id;
    foreach($query:results as $directory){
        $directories[] = $directory:id;
        $query2 = SELECT `id` FROM `files` WHERE `directory_id` = $directory:id;
        foreach($query2:results as $file){
            $files[] = $file:id
        }
        delete_tree($directory:id, $files, $directories);
    }
}

$query = DELETE from `directories` WHERE `id` IN (explode(',', $directories));
$query = DELETE from `files` WHERE `id` IN (explode(',', $files));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use recursive sql ;-)

here you can find infos:

http://wiki.yaslaw.info/wikka/MySQLTree

Under "4).." you find a sample for the sql condition you need.

here the sample code:

```
SELECT
    nav.id,
    nav.title
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rownum, 
            IF(@lastid <> mylist.id, @id := mylist.id, @id) AS pathid,
            @lastid := mylist.id AS id,
            @id := (SELECT parentID FROM nav  WHERE id = @id) AS parentID
        FROM
            (SELECT @id := 0, @lastid := 0, @rownum := 0) AS vars,
            (SELECT id FROM nav) AS myloop,
            (SELECT id FROM nav) AS mylist
    ) AS t
    INNER JOIN nav
        ON t.id = nav.id
WHERE
    pathid = 2  // all subitems from id=2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it through database constraints.

Suppose I have the following tables

[image]

I can define both relations so that the records will be deleted in cascades by deleting of the main record.

Example in phpMyAdmin:

//directories

[image]

//files

[image]

Now I delete the directory "03" with id=10

//directories

[image]

//files

[image]

As you can see, all the records from both tables, which were children of the node were deleted. Very quickly and without any scripts.

Here is a small dump:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `directories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1250 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

INSERT INTO `directories` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`) VALUES (0, 'root', 0),(6, '02', 0), (10, '03', 0),(11, '031', 10),(12, '032', 10);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `directory_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `directory_id` (`directory_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1250 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


INSERT INTO `files` (`id`, `name`, `directory_id`) VALUES (2, '031_f01', 11),(3, '031_f02', 11),(4, '02_f01', 6),(6, '02_f02', 6);


ALTER TABLE `directories`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `directories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `directories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `files`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `files_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`directory_id`) REFERENCES `directories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```